Typescript Polymorphic Component Event Handler
I have written a strongly-typed Polymorphic Typescript React component that can accept any valid HTML tag.  I followed this example here: https://www.tsteele.dev/posts/react-polymorphic-forwardref.
// polymorphic component with forwarded ref thanks to
// https://www.tsteele.dev/posts/react-polymorphic-forwardref
// https://gist.github.com/kripod/4434e7cecfdecee160026aee49ea6ee8

import React, {
  forwardRef,
  useCallback,
  type ComponentPropsWithRef,
  type ElementType,
  type JSX,
  type JSXElementConstructor,
  type Ref,
} from 'react';

type IntrinsicAttributes<
  E extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements | JSXElementConstructor<any>,
> = JSX.LibraryManagedAttributes<E, ComponentPropsWithRef<E>>;

export interface BoxOwnProps<E extends ElementType = ElementType> {
  as?: E;
}

export type BoxProps<E extends ElementType> = BoxOwnProps<E> &
  Omit<IntrinsicAttributes<E>, keyof BoxOwnProps>;

export const Box = forwardRef(function Box(
  { as: Element = 'div', ...restProps }: BoxOwnProps,
  ref: Ref<Element>
) {
  const handleOnClick = useCallback((ev: HTMLElement) => {
    //    The type error is on the next line (see image)
    console.log(ev.currentTarget);
  }, []);

  return <Element ref={ref} onClick={handleOnClick} {...restProps} />;
}) as <E extends ElementType = 'div'>(props: BoxProps<E>) => JSX.Element;

For the handleOnClick callback, I assigned the event in the callback the HTMLElement type from @types/react-dom because it is the parent of all possible HTML dom elements and was generic enough to satisfy TypeScript.
But, I now specifically need access to the event.currentTarget property.

The only way I know of to make TypeScript aware of the currentTarget property is to change HTMLElement to a more specific type, like HTMLButtonElement. But that breaks polymorphism because the developer could pick a tag like "a" which means I would need to change the callback event type to HTMLAnchorElement
Is there a generic React Typescript type for HTMLElement that accepts a tag string?  Like HTMLElement<'button'>. I'm just not aware of a generic type that can allow me to set the event conditionally based on an HTML tag name.

Ugh... this all comes down to a typo.  Line 26 in the screen shot should be ev: React.MouseEvent or ev: React.MouseEvent<HtmlElement>.  Either would work.

HTMLElement is the type of the dom element. You are using that type for a parameter of a callback for an event coming from the dom element. Those aren't the same thing.
Try:
const handleOnClick = useCallback((ev: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
  console.log(ev.currentTarget);
}, []);


Thanks.  It was just a typo.  I was just fatigued from a long coding session and couldn't see it.
